# OpenCV 3.2.0: Reading Canny image for training SVM

Tags: c++, opencv, opencv3.0

I'm having problem reading the edge image for training SVM:

```
int numFiles = 1;
int imgArea = 60 * 60; //canny image size
Mat trainingMat(numFiles, imgArea, CV_32FC1);// or  CV_8UC3

Mat imgMat = imread("C://canny.jpg");
int ii = 0; // Current column in trainingMat
for (int i = 0; i<imgMat.rows; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < imgMat.cols; j++) {
        trainingMat.at<float>(numFiles, ii++) = imgMat.at<uchar>(i, j); --> here the error
    }
}
Mat labels(numFiles, 1, CV_32FC1);

Ptr<ml::SVM> svm = ml::SVM::create();
svm->setType(ml::SVM::C_SVC);
svm->setKernel(ml::SVM::LINEAR);
svm->setGamma(3);

svm->train(trainingMat, ml::ROW_SAMPLE, labels);
svm->save("svm_filename");
svm->load("svm_filename");

//test image using the trained svm
Mat imgMatTest = imread("C://canny1.jpg");
svm->predict(imgMatTest);
```

The exception I'm getting at :

```
trainingMat.at<float>(numFiles, ii++) = imgMat.at<uchar>(i, j);
```

Unhandled exception at 0x000007FEFCE4A06D in test.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x000000000015F300.

which refers to :

```
CV_DbgAssert((unsigned)i0 < (unsigned)size.p[0]);
```

I have tried it with "uchar" as well but getting the same exception. Could someone please guide me how to fix this problem and if there will be more problems in the rest of the code after fixing the current one?

Comment: `Mat trainingMat(numFiles, imgArea, CV_8UC3);` shoudn't it be a `CV_32FC1` since you're accessing its values with `.at<float>`?

Comment: @Miki  the same exception occures when using CV_32FC1 as well!

Comment: You're loading the `imgMat` as `CV_8UC3`. Use `Mat imgMat = imread("C://canny.jpg", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);` to lead it as a `CV_8UC1`. I recommend to study a little about `cv::Mat`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that imgMat is of type CV_8UC3 (whether it actually has color or not).

When you access imgMat with imgMat.at, the accessing method expects a CV_8UC1, which is not the case.

Before the loop, convert the image to grayscale and it shouldn't crash.

```
cv::Mat gray;
cv::cvtColor(imgMat, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
```